When I make an auth phone with Firebase Server connection failed for URL
My problem is, am I getting this error because recaptcha redirection is being done in the meantime?
Server connection failed for url: https://remoteprovisioning.googleapis.com/v1:signCertificates?challenge=AAABj0rwhPYBILStY-CiXiqz8_p2YT2WWl4x3I8=&request_id=c5797711-bada-4ed7-a986-3207c4bc7e4e,
response code: 400
                 Repeated failure count: 1
{
                   "error": {
                     "code": 400,
                     "message": "Invalid request payload: vendor_patch_level should in the format YYYYMMDD or YYYYMM if present.\nRequestId: c5797711-bada-4ed7-a986-3207c4bc7e4e",
                     "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
                   }
}
failed to provision keys
com.android.rkpdapp.RkpdException: HTTP error status encountered: 400                   
error fetching key for client 15801866: ERROR_UNKNOWN: HTTP error status encountered: 400
system/security/keystore2/src/rkpd_client.rs:172 - IGetKeyCallback failed: ERROR_UNKNOWN: HTTP error status encountered: 400
Encountered exception whilst fetching from GMS, deferring to Finsky: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: IntegrityApiDisplayListener.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}


Please help
First of all, I tried creating multiple different firebase projects and got the same error.
I tried entering my phone number in different ways and got the same error in all of them.
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val binding = FragmentLoginBinding.bind(view)
        _binding = binding

        auth = Firebase.auth

        callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks(){

            override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
                Log.i("errorPhone","onVerificationCompleted")

            }

            override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
                Log.i("errorPhone","this Area = inSide")

                if (e is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                    Log.i("errorPhone",e.toString())
                } else if (e is FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                    // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                    Log.i("errorPhone",e.toString())

                } else if (e is FirebaseAuthMissingActivityForRecaptchaException) {
                    // reCAPTCHA verification attempted with null Activity
                    Log.i("errorPhone",e.toString())

                }
            }

            override fun onCodeSent(
                verificationId: String,
                token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken,
            ) {
                // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
                // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
                // by combining the code with a verification ID.

                // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
                storedVerificationId = verificationId
                resendToken = token
                Log.i("errorPhone","this Area = " + storedVerificationId.toString())
                //val action = LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToOtpVerifyFragment()
                Navigation.findNavController(requireView()).navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_otpVerifyFragment)

            }
        }

        binding.loginBtn.setOnClickListener {
            sendVerificationCode(binding.phoneNumberEdT.text.toString())
        }

    }


    private fun sendVerificationCode(phoneNumber: String){
        val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
            .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) // Phone number to verify
            .setTimeout(30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
            .setActivity(requireActivity()) // Activity (for callback binding)
            .setCallbacks(callbacks) // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            .build()
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
        Log.i("errorPhone",phoneNumber)
    }

In the code above, first enter the sendverificationCode() function and carries out the transactions.
Inside the onViewCreated() function, there are functions that are overridden for callbacks.
I can enter the onCodeSent() function and get the storedVerificationId.
My problem is, am I getting this error because recaptcha redirection is being done in the meantime?
